# Failed to fetch error while updating

Tags: apt, updates

This comes after I input sudo apt update

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 2600:9000:21fe:5e00:1c:3aaa:b100:93a1 443]
E: The repository 'https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. I do not see a Ubuntu version stated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)  (these answers primarily apply to PPAs, but your source is a 3rd party repository as well so same applies, for you *unstated* OS & release)

Comment: You have to ask TeamViewer support about their repository.